# Accessing local dns from local devices using dnsmasq

Tags: macos, dns, localhost, dnsmasq

I got a webserver running on my Mac on `localhost:3000` and I am trying to set a local DNS with `dnsmasq` and to be able to access that DNS from local devices (iPhone / iPad) for test purpose.

I followed this previous post:
[iPhone: add entry to /etc/hosts without jailbreaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473939/iphone-add-entry-to-etc-hosts-without-jailbreaking)

I am looking to redirect all *.localhost here

`dnsmasq.conf`:

[image: .conf]

`/etc/resolver/localhost`:

[image: /etc/resolver/localhost]

`dig google.com`:

[image: dig google.com]

The Mac Network DNS config:

[image: Mac Network DNS config]

On my phone, on the same network, adding the Mac Local IP as DNS:

`Wi-Fi is connected to xxxxxx and has the IP address 192.168.1.11.`

[image: phone DNS]

I am able to connect to `myapp.localhost:3000` successfully on the Mac but getting `Server cannot be found` on the iPhone.

Must be missing something there.

---

## EDIT #0: 2021/07/08

`netstat -anvp tcp | grep '\b192.168.1.11.53\b'` output:

[image]

Comment: Your router should already have a DNS server (at least, any sold within the last decade do). You don't need a DNS server to access `http://192.168.1.11:3000` over the LAN anyway

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and use `netstat` to check if your dnsmasq is open on 192.168.1.11

if the result is similar to

```
root@dns-01:~# sudo netstat -tnlp
  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53         0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       13376/dnsmasq
```

it means that it will only accept queries from the local machine, not from your network.

to query from your network you must see something like

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:53      0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       13376/dnsmasq
```

or

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53           0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       104287/dnsmasq
```

Comment: thx a lot for the effort. I edited the question with the output.